# Login Heroku bash, edit file, then restart app without re-push

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm deploying a Docker app to Heroku, and it takes a little while every push, even for a small configuration change like a url variable.

Is it possible to modify the variable directly on Heroku, then restart the app without waiting for push again?

I can access Heroku with `heroku run bash`, then edit and save the file. But the app does not take effect. How do I restart the app with new configuration file? If I do `heroku restart`, my edit is erased, the app is restarted with old configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify the variable directly on Heroku, then restart the app without waiting for push again?

Not if you mean editing a file.

Heroku provides an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) that loses any changes made to it whenever each dyno restarts. In fact, when you run `heroku run bash` you don't even connect to the dyno(s) running your application. [Heroku spins up a brand new "one-off" dyno for you that gets discarded as soon as you exit](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno).

> it takes a little while every push, even for a small configuration change like a url variable

Heroku encourages you to [configure your application via its environment](https://12factor.net/config). If you load your "URL variable" from the environment you can [modify it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) more-or-less on the fly (technically this causes your application to restart, resulting in a new release, but it doesn't require a new build).